# Angular mdChips Autocomplete prevent delete on backspace

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

See the demo pages on https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/chips

I would like to prevent a chip from being deleted when continually hitting the backspace button. I have no idea how to do this. Can anyone guide me?

Answer (score 0):

Not a perfect solution but you can try to push the chip back to the list by using md-on-remove.

```
<md-chips ng-model=ctrl.fruits"" md-on-remove="ctrl.addToList($chip)">
```